# Computer won't go into standby

Tags: windows-media-center, shutdown, htpc, standby, magicjack

When I select Start->Turn off computer->Standby the 'turn off computer' option window closes, and then nothing else happens.  I can start new applications, and Windows acts like I never selected standby. I ran it for several hours after that.  If I have a TV program scheduled to record when I select standby I get a window (the Pinnacle TV software) asking if I'm sure, there are programs scheduled to record - and the computer just keeps running after I select yes, never going into standby.  I added that detail as it shows the standby process is starting. [This problem also happens if a TV program is not scheduled, so the scheduler task in not running/in memory.  This problem happens regardless of whether I'm not watching TV.  This problem happens regardless of whether Media Center is running (it usually isn't, I'm using Pinnacle to watch TV).]

I looked at "How to troubleshoot hibernation and standby issues in Windows XP" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907477 - ACPI is enabled, and "standby" is an option in "Power Options Properties."  So it appears to be setup correctly.

Windows XP SP3 Media Center Edition, all current updates installed.

Comment: Can you provide some technical specs on your computer, especially the motherboard make/model.  If it's an older motherboard, it may not support Standby mode.

Comment: The computer was brand new in 2008... The link I quoted above says if those things show up as option then it's supported and set up correctly.

Comment: The motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-MA78GM-S2H, the processor is an AMD Athlon Dual Core 4850e, 2.51 GHz. BIOS = "Award Software International, F8, 6/3/2009 SMBIOS Version 2.4." It's a desktop.

Comment: WHY DID YOU EDIT MY TITLE, quack quixote - I DON'T HAVE A DVR! What is HTPC?

Comment: @robert: i changed "tv" to "htpc/dvr" -- "htpc" is "home theater pc", "dvr" is "digital video recorder", both are used to refer to computers configured to play/record tv video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this through trial and error.  Killing MagicJack (internet phone) solves the problem.

Comment: I may not be back in two days to mark this answer as accepted - it says I have to wait that long.